# Auto remember-me after register

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

I'm using Symfony 5.2 / PHP8

My login form is simply email + password I do an auto "remember me" using

```
    firewalls:
        endusers:
            ...
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /
                always_remember_me: true
```

this works without any issue

The problem is during registration, I autologin the user using this snippet

```
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
                user: $user,
                credentials: null,
                firewallName: 'endusers',
                roles: $user->getRoles(),
            );
            $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
            $this->container->get('session')->set('_security_endusers', serialize($token))
```

and while this work, it unfortunately does not trigger the remember me feature
(which is normal to my understanding, as the remember me  is trigger normally one level higher by the 'onloginsuccess' event which is not triggered here)

So I would like to know how to have also the remember me set up in the case above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update Symfony 5.3

There's now a `RememberMeHandlerInterface` service that works with autowiring, so you simply need to inject it and use it like this

```
            $rememberMe->createRememberMeCookie($user);
```

no need to update your services.yaml

## Symfony 5.2

You can create the `remember_me` cookie by using [`RememberMeServicesInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/5.2/RememberMe/RememberMeServicesInterface.php) and calling `loginSuccess`.
There's no autowiring service for it, though, so you have to create an alias in order to inject it in your controller.

The container alias for the service is `security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.<firewall_name>`. Depending on the configuration it could be other than `simplehash`, you can verify it by executing  `bin/console debug:container rememberme.services`.

Once you've verified the registered service, create the alias in `config/services.yaml`:

```
services:
     # ...
     Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\RememberMeServicesInterface:
         alias: security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.endusers
```

Now you can inject the service in your controller and call the function after successful registration.

```
public function register(Request $request, RememberMeServicesInterface $rememberme, /* Other deps */)
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'endusers', $user->getRoles());
        
    $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->container->get('session')->set('_security_endusers', serialize($token));
    
    // RememberMe needs a Response object so cookies can be set in the output
    $response = $this->redirectToRoute($route);
    
    $rememberme->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);
    
    return $response;
}
```

According to your firewall configuration, `always_remember_me` is enabled, but in case it weren't, you'd need to set the `remember_me_parameter` (`_remember_me` by default) in the request for the service to actually create the cookie.

```
$request->attributes->add(['_remember_me' => true]);
$rememberme->loginSuccess(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Did nor work for me, in Symfony 5.2. i get the following error: You have requested a non-existent service "security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.endusers".

Comment: @dompie change `endusers` with your firewall name, it'll be most likely `main`. You can check your `security.yaml` configuration or execute the aforemention `console` command to be sure.